# Error loading page when load the page through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I load different pages through Ajax to replace content of DIV("myPage") in master page, but I got "error loading pages" each time when click footer link to load the page. Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chat").click(function(){
        $('#myPage').load('./chat.html');
        $('#title').load('./constants.html #chat');
    })
    $("#address").click(function()
    {
        $('#myPage').load('./address.html');
        $('#title').load('./constants.html #address');
    })
})

</script>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1 id="title"></h1>
    </div>

    <div id="myPage" data-role="content"></div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="nav-custom" style="overflow:hidden;" id="myFooter" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" >
        <div data-role="navbar"  class="nav-custom"  >
            <ul>
                <li><a href="function()"  id="chat" data-icon="custom">Chat</a></li>
                <li><a href="function()"  id="address" data-icon="custom">Address</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the xhr response look like in the console

Comment: What does the console say? - I smell a `HTTP 404`.

Comment: And why do you have `href="function()"`? If you don't want anchor to lead anywhere, set it to `href="javascript:void(0)"`, or use <button> element.

Comment: I did not see 404 error. When click "chat" button on nav bar after the master page has been shown, $("#chat").click(function() will be called and the chat.html will be loaded by $('#myPage') and the page actually was shown well with the "error loading page" message displayed at same time. When people click different button in nav bar, i want to lead to different page, so i use href="function()".

Comment: I put <button> into navbar instead of <a>, and the error is gone. Thank you, Davion.